# Security implications of textarea direct to DOM

Tags: javascript, html, security

I have a requirement to paste text from a textarea into the DOM as a preview area, much like the one you get on Stackoverflow when you make a comment etc.

I allow users to insert any and all html tags, including javascript tags. I know this will allow embedded javascript and flash content etc, but I then remove all of this server side so no other user will see, they just see plain text.

However are there any security issues in letting the user insert these things in there own page?

My guess is there isn't otherwise tools like firebug would be a security risk, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However are there any security issues in letting the user insert these things in there own page?

I can't see any - the DOM is freely manipulable in the client's browser, anyway. Whether they do it using a tool like Firebug or your JavaScript function, doesn't matter.

As long as the data isn't shown unfiltered in other users' browsers, I think you're safe doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Actually in rare set of circumstance, it might be an issue. It highly depends on how this particular feature works, but I can imagine making first use of CSRF to 'post' in the preview area some malicious javascript/ajax, and use that to steal cookies, change account password or whatever tickles your fancy.

So the attack would go something like this; I send a user a link to a 'legitimate' website. On that website there is a hidden payload (eg via img tag in case of GET, or hidden iframe with auto-submitting form for POST) which silently redirects the user to your website with the XSS payload, which then will be executed by the user through the injection in the preview area, for instance logging user's cookies, without him ever knowing.

Again it all depends how your preview feature works, and if you for instance use form tokens etc., but the point is that it in fact could be an issue.

Comment: So basically you mean if there is a way to put text into the textarea from an exteral source, e.g. via a query string or via a post, then it would be an issue?

Comment: yeah that's exactly it, but I assumed that you use just some jquery magic, hence the 'rare set of circumstance' (although I have seen versions with some ajax involved). But still I figured better to cover the far fetched possibility rather than regretting it later

Comment: You're right it's just done with jQuery, but yeah worth mentioning.